# AppDelegate not using instance variables

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appdelegate

I have two class files and i'm trying to use variables from one another. it seems i must be missing something or not initializing something correct:

.h - AppDelegate

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {

    NSString *extString;

}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *extString;

- (void)extStringSetter;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MoarDelegates.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize extString;

NSString *someString;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    [self extStringSetter];

}

- (void)extStringSetter {

    MoarDelegates *dualString = [[MoarDelegates alloc] init];
    dualString.someString = @"world!";

    NSLog(@"%@",someString);
}

@end
```

.h - MoarDelgates

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class AppDelegate;

@interface MoarDelegates : NSObject {

    NSString *someString;
    AppDelegate *appdelegate;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) AppDelegate *appdelegate;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *someString;


- (void)someStringSetter;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "MoarDelegates.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation MoarDelegates

@synthesize appdelegate;
@synthesize someString;

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init]) != nil) {
        appdelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    }

    [self someStringSetter];

    return self;
}

- (void)someStringSetter {

    AppDelegate *dualString = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    dualString.extString = @"world!";

    NSLog(@"%@",someString);
}

@end
```

ouput:

```
(null)
(null)
```

yes. i'm a novice at obj-c, so please don't rake me over the fire. i come from a long lineage of bookworms - and i'm here to learn.

Comment: Let's start with: any time you're creating app delegates in your program, you're probably doing something really wrong.  Apart from that, you are setting values inside objects and then printing variables that are not from those objects…therefore, the <null> results.  Third thing, sort of related, when you declare properties you should mostly use them as properties rather than touching the variables that are behind them.

Comment: Thinking about this some more….  Be sure that you understand that `alloc` means to create a new object of its type that's generally, by default, not going to share any data with other objects of that type.  It doesn't mean "give me access to an already existing object".

Comment: @PhillipMills, So should I not be concerned that everything is contained within one class and header file? I know that I can make it work if I go that route. That brings me to another question; is it more efficient to contain everything within the fewest class files as possible? I more or less wanted to use multiple files just to clean up the current extensively long class file i've been using. And is does breaking the application into multiple files add more overhead after it's compiled? thanks

Comment: Use multiple files…the compiler and linker will deal with those kinds of efficiency concerns!  When considering behaviour, think about objects rather than files.  For example, if you change the `init` in MoarDelegates into something like `initWithDelegate:(AppDelegate *)del` and pass it `self` when it's called from `AppDelegate`, then you're talking to the same object.  (You'll find other problems but it's a step in the right direction.)